# Are there good ways for an Indian company to wire money to an individual in Mainland China?

Tags: india, money-transfer, international-trading, international-transfer, china

Are there good ways for an Indian company to wire money to an individual in Mainland China?

Answer (score 1):

HSBC, also known as "The Hong Kong and Shanghai Banking Corporation" has banks in India.
I would imagine that might be a place to start.

Paypal, which is commonly used to pay for items on eBay -- is also available in both India and China.

You should, of course, respect any laws regulating this kind of money transfer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

- SWIFT transfer : ask your counterparty for his bank SWIFT code and beneficiary account numbers; you can do a SWIFT transfer to most countries from your Indian bank). You will need to fill a form where they ask you what you're transferring the money for, etc. Most Indian banks provide this facility.
- Western Union: I'm not sure if WU is in China, but they are very simple to use.
- Paypal: They charge heavy fees, but may be the fastest way to get your money across.